# How can I install adobe flash on my Windows Mobile 6.5 phone?

Tags: flash, windows-mobile, window

I have an htc Imagio.  I cannot seem to find a Flash Player for it.  Does anyone know how to get Flash to install on a Windows Mobile 6.5 phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Flash Lite for Windows Mobile](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/wm.html).

Comment: I thought so, but when I install it no flash required content works.